# Detecting certain Parse reset password errors

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I am trying to detect the errors when people try to reset their passwords. I tried code similar to the signup and login ones, but don't work. Here is  my code:

```
PFUser.requestPasswordResetForEmailInBackground(finalEmail!)

if error == 125 {

}
```

EDIT: This is defined when a user clicks a button and I'm trying to figure out how to detect certain errors, as finalEmail doesn't have an identifier called 'error'

Comment: Show actual code, what is the error you're interrogating? Where is it defined?

Comment: This is defined when a user clicks a button and I'm trying to figure out how to detect certain errors, as finalEmail doesn't have an identifier called 'error'

Comment: Because it's a string, and you're ignoring the task returned from the function?

Comment: I'm trying to work out how to add errors, so I can detect the certain errors and give them custom error messages to alert the user.